Does Charles Proxy still work to intercept HTTP traffic on mobile iOS?
I set up the proxy on my phone to point to 10.242.242.79, (port 8888 for Charles), which is the wifi IP on my Mac, but all it does is disconnect the phone from the network--no internet connectivity at all.
Charles Proxy DOES work on the simulator, but apparently doesn't pick up my custom API URLs, although it does capture OneSignal and Bugsnag.
ADDITIONAL INFO
Doesn't work with Burp either. Do I have to configure MacOS proxy setting somehow?
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-proxy-settings-on-mac-mchlp2591/mac

Did you install And trust the root certificate on the device?

Impossible to do that, because setting the proxy does not work, and therefore the internet is not active. you install the certificate after you've set up the proxy. If you can't do A, then you can't do B.

could it be the cable? I'm using a USB to lightning cable with a USB to USBC adapter to plug into a USBC port on an M3 macbook.

That wasn't it. Swapped cabled for a USBC to lightning, made no difference.

And now I am completely confused. CP works fine at home on my M1 Mac Mini. Spectrum cable network. Doesn't work on any machine in my office. Verizon FIOS.
Do I have to change proxy setting somewhere, somehow, on the Mac? Why on one machine but not on the other? Why is this so difficult, with two nearly identical installations?

Also, the Charles root certificate WON'T INSTALL AT ALL on the Intel machine. Installs in the keychain on the M3, you have to then set to "Trust All"
